# iOS: Zoom in/out animation for showing an UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one view controller, where i have two buttons. Clicking on one button, i'll show an UIView (size: 900 * 600) programmatically. Right now, this view comes just like that clicking on that button action. But, i want to have this view coming as if kind of "zoom in" animation and show to the user, and when user closes this view, it will go like "zoom out" and removed from parent view.

Could you please suggest me, how i can achieve this animation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The property `transform` is animatable.
So create CGAffineTransformMakeScale with destination scale factor, and set the

```
view.transform = scaleTransform;
```

inside the animation block.

Comment: Read Apple docu how to make animations. Animations are made within an animation block. (or previously with "startAnimation")